# Ubuntu + Pound 3.0 (load balancer) errors when on port 80

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load-balancing, sysadmin, pound

When I start up pound with service it does not log the error in syslog but when I start it with 'pound -d 3'

7F1384113640 thr_http start /build/pound-lNcD5I/pound-3.0/src/http.c:535
7F1384113640 start loop /build/pound-lNcD5I/pound-3.0/src/http.c:539
Listener 64.62.211.170:http: can't bind socket
Listener 64.62.211.171:http: can't bind socket

Config is:

/etc/pound/pound.yaml

### Minimal sample configuration

### see pound(8) for details

### NOTE: pound currently only seems to work with non-loopback

### addresses. This sample therefore will not work until adapted.

Global:
User:         "_pound"
Group:        "_pound"
#User:                "root"
#Group:       "root"
#RootJail     "/chroot/pound"

Backends:

- &be
  Address: 192.168.0.4 # node8
  Port: 80
- &bf
  Address: 192.168.0.15 # node4
  Port: 80
- &bg
  Address: 192.168.0.8 # node7
  Port: 80

## This section must exist, but may be empty.

HTTPListeners:

- Address: x.x.x.x
  #- Address: 192.168.0.14
  Port: 80
  Services:

  - Backends:

    - *be
      #- Address: ::1
- Address: x.x.x.x
  Port: 80
  Services:

  - Backends:

    - *bf
    - *bg

## This section must exist, but may be empty.

HTTPSListeners:
********** End Config

```
                                                                                                         Any insights on how to run pound properly would be great.
```

Thank You!

Comment: wozld it not ve easier for you to use apache nginx or haproxy instead such a exotic software?

Comment: The error is pretty definitive. “Can’t bind,” to the http port (80). Remove the offending service from port 80 before trying to use it with Pound. Something else already has this port.